# R - Within Loop: On match criteria set variable next line below

Tags: r, loops, match

I have a loop at which I am trying to edit that on matching criteria, the variable is to set on the next line below. Right now its set that is there is `signal == 1`, it would store that `close.detrend.n11` price for future comparisons. However, i wish to on `signal == 1`, store the next `close.detrend.n11` price on the next line down.

If we take this portion of code:

```
state <- "off"
    for (i in 1:nrow(new.df)) { # loop through data
      if (state == "off") { # off state, loop does nothing until signal = 1
        if (new.df$signal[i] == 0) {
          next
        } else { # signal = 1 encountered
          comparison_price <- new.df$close.detrend.n11[i] # save current price for comparing
          n_comparisons <- 0              # keep track of how many comparisons
          state <- "on"                   # change state to "on"
        }
```

The part that finds a signal == 1 is `} else { # signal = 1`next it then sets comparison_price on the same line as signal == 1, it saves the `close.detrend.n11` price for future comparisons.

Goal is to that on signal == 1, its to set the comparison price on +1 line BELOW signal == 1. The loop is then to function as intended.

The whole code is here for reproduction purposes or for other research purposes, looks like its quite a nifty piece of code that can be used.

```
new.df <- data.frame(new.df,response=0)
input <- new.df$close.detrend.n11 # Input column for code
signal <- new.df$detrend.signal.n11
nlines <- 10 # Time Stop

state <- "off"
for (i in 1:nrow(new.df)) { # loop through data
  if (state == "off") { # off state, loop does nothing until signal = 1
    if (signal[i] == 0) {
      next
    } else { # signal = 1 encountered, if not a 0 it will do whats below...
      comparison_price <- input[i] # save current price for comparing
      n_comparisons <- 0              # keep track of how many comparisons
      state <- "on"                   # change state to "on"
    }
  } else if (state == "on") { # Above turned on as found signal = 1
    new.df$response[i] <- 1 
    if (input[i] > comparison_price & n_comparisons >= 1) { # found higher price
      state <- "off" # Turns off as found higer price, now does nothing until signal == 1
    } else if (n_comparisons == 10) { # Shut off maximum travel on higher prices
      state <- "off"  # Turns off as max limit reached
      n_comparisons <- 0   # Sets count to 0
      if (signal[i] == 1) {  # Find signal match
        comparison_price <- input[i] + 1 # Set price for comparing
        n_comparisons <- 0 # Sets count to 0
        state <- "off"    # Turn off 
      }
    } else if (n_comparisons == nlines) { # hit comparison limit
      state <- "off"  # Turns off as max limit reached
      n_comparisons <- 0   # Sets count to 0
      if (signal[i] == 1) { # Finds signal ==1
        comparison_price <- input[i] # Set price for comparing
        n_comparisons <- 0 # Set count to 0
        state <- "on" # Turn On
      }
    } else { # price less or equal to comparison price
      n_comparisons <- n_comparisons + 1
    }
  }
}
```

The code above will produce an output as below:

`new.df` below:

```
  detrend.signal.n11 response close.detrend.n11
1                   0        0       0.002044539
2                   0        0      -0.022593487
3                   1        0      -0.031842265
4                   1        1      -0.065392575
5                   0        1      -0.043699817
6                   0        1      -0.014110718
7                   0        0      -0.021899531
8                   0        0      -0.013908376
9                   0        0      -0.019580252
10                  0        0       0.023034983
11                  0        0       0.014598769
12                  0        0       0.013928860
13                  0        0       0.008568669
14                  0        0       0.020220697
15                  0        0      -0.003770356
16                  0        0      -0.021588957
17                  0        0      -0.018637185
18                  0        0      -0.007193684
19                  0        0      -0.013691624
20                  0        0      -0.020903833
21                  1        0      -0.036922613
22                  0        1      -0.011845136
23                  0        1       0.001115208
24                  0        0       0.018121000
25                  0        0       0.027648296
26                  0        0       0.016920882
27                  0        0       0.006321574
28                  0        0      -0.012052026
29                  0        0      -0.017340348
30                  0        0      -0.029062592
31                  0        0      -0.012560974
32                  0        0      -0.029126952
33                  0        0      -0.026220867
34                  0        0       0.007337385
35                  0        0       0.009356641
36                  0        0       0.027851405
37                  0        0       0.044130597
38                  0        0       0.036630768
39                  0        0       0.028685373
40                  0        0       0.030813270
41                  0        0       0.020690203
42                  0        0       0.014865516
43                  0        0      -0.001644471
44                  0        0       0.011208823
45                  0        0       0.009698927
```

Sorry its a mammoth of a question or a crazy example.

The main question is how to +1 a line below an initial match inside a loop is the main question.

Comment: Have you looked at `lead()` in `dplyr`?

Comment: well this is using base R... is it in dplyr? can i use another package command within this loop?

Comment: You "reproducible code" does not have your `new.df` so it cannot quite be used. Can you provide a snippet for us to run?

Comment: Try now: i added the response = 0 column to the new.df. Should be able to reproduce

Comment: Base R has no "new.df" in the environment. That is your data.

Comment: Oh sorry, need to load my pasted new.df to a .txt and load from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this in base R

```
# Simulate `lead` in `dplyr`
future.detrend <- close.detrend.nll[2:nrow(df)]

# iterate through df, if signal ==1, keep future.detrend value, else NA
next.close.detrend.nll <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) ifelse(df$detrend.signal.nll[x]==1, future.detrend[x], NA))
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer here however can we think of anything to add within the loop?